# How to map folder on C: to non existing drive D:

Tags: windows, windows-10, mapped-drive

On my desktop PC I have the folders:

```
D:\documents\Lightroom
D:\documents\Pictures
```

In order to work with my Lightroom catalog on my laptop, that only has a drive C: I created the folder `C:\documents`. Now I'm trying to create some sort of mapping so that I can use `D:\documents` on my laptop.

I've tried:

```
mklink /j D:\documents C:\Documents
```

But that gives me a cannot find path specified error message. Maybe because there is no D: to begin with.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`subst`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command:

```
subst D: C:\documents
```

Then you'll have a "drive" that is directly linked to the folder you specified and even shows up on the Explorer window.

Additionally, you could share the `C:\documents` folder and give it permission to your user only, then you could use the [`net use`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) command to map it like a network drive with read/write permissions:

```
net use D: \\your_pc_name\documents
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but the folder and it's contents show up read-only.

Comment: If the `subst` command is making it show up read-only, have you checked the permissions of the folder, or run the command prompt with elevated privileges?

Comment: When I open cmd as administator and run subst, I don't see d:\ in explorer, only in cmd.

Comment: It is for the user you run command for.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1135177/146810), with `subst` you can map a drive to a local folder **temporarily** (which means, after a reboot it is gone).

But there is another way to create a **permanent** drive mapped to a local folder.

Right-click to create a new text file (let's name it `MapDriveD.txt`).
Paste the following into it (Note that the first line must be exactly `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` followed by a blank line):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"D:"="\\??\\C:\\Users\\myWinUser\\Documents"
```

The local Windows user name (here: `myWinUser`) and its related path `C:\Users\myWinUser\Documents` need to exist.

Then, rename `.txt` to `.reg` and finally run `MapDriveD.reg` with elevated (administrator) rights, for example from an administrator command prompt.

After a reboot, you will have a permanent drive `D:` which points diretly into `C:\Users\myWinUser\Documents`.

---

**Note:** Of course, if you remove `\\Documents` in the `.reg` file, you can also map drive `D:` to `C:\Users\myWinUser`, and then you have the path `D:\Documents` you asked for.